# Detect skin tone from image programatically

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation, face-detection

Does anyone have any advice about how to find the skin tone from image in iOS?

It is a bit of an obscure question but I am hoping to get help from you.
I have found several questions related to the topic:

[get face skin tone color from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709433/get-face-skin-tone-color-from-image)

[Detect skin tone from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700389/detect-skin-tone-from-an-image)

Any sort of advice would be greatly appreciated because I'm currently at a loss for what to do in swift.

Comment: A good start point: [Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/48367205#48367205)

Comment: @Silencer金, Thanks for sharing the useful link. Though I am not able to understand it fully, it would be great if you can share some more information.